# Field order for Where clause

Tags: select, abap, database-performance

I've discovered, that field order impacts on Select performance. For example, I want to extract data from view `V_EUQI` by `TPLNR`(500), `DATBI`(1) and `EQTYP`(1), the sentence:

```
SELECT ... FROM v_equi INTO itab
 WHERE eqtyp IN rg_eqtyp
   AND datbi IN rg_datbi
   AND tplnr IN rg_tplnr
```

runs much more faster, than same select, but field order `TPLNR`-`EQTYP`-`DATBI`.

How to explain this problem?

Comment: Are you completely and definitely sure that the contents of the range tables are absolutely identical? Could you please provide screenshots of the analyze results from the SQL trace (ST05) for both variants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly indexing related. When reading from a transparent table, for maximum performance the order of the fields in the `WHERE` clause should either match those of an index or the left-to-right order of the fields in the table (to take advantage of any implicit index created from the primary key(s)). Indexes cannot be defined for views, but any defined for the underlying tables will certainly be used.

You should be able to confirm this using a SQL trace and confirming which indexes are used.